# This graphing technique works in my head, why not in RL?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Alright, I am trying to create a graph that changes every second and just shows a 3 second history. In my head it would make sense to tie it into the T variable (Time in seconds), so I have form1 outputting T to a text box on form2 and then everytime that textbox changes it graphs the new chart.

The reason I am doing the step ladder approach is because I wanted the numbers to appear under the points as they travel.

does this make any sense at all, or am I completely off base?

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form2

    Dim chart1 As New Chart

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox11_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox10.TextChanged

        If Form1.T <= 2 Then

            Label1.Visible = False

            TextBox20.Text = TextBox21.Text
            TextBox31.Text = TextBox32.Text

                TextBox21.Text = TextBox22.Text
            TextBox32.Text = TextBox33.Text

            TextBox22.Text = Form1.TextBox10.Text
            TextBox33.Text = Form1.TextBox4.Text

            Dim s1() As Point = {New Point(Form1.T - 2, TextBox20.Text), New Point(Form1.T - 1, TextBox21.Text), New Point(Form1.T, TextBox22.Text)}
            Dim s2() As Point = {New Point(Form1.T - 2, TextBox31.Text), New Point(Form1.T - 1, TextBox32.Text), New Point(Form1.T, TextBox33.Text)}
            For x As Integer = Form1.T - 2 To Form1.T
                chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(x, s1(x).Y)
            Next

            chart1.Series.Add("Series2")

            chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
            chart1.Series(1).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

            For x As Integer = Form1.T - 2 To Form1.T
                chart1.Series(1).Points.Add(x, s1(x).Y)
            Next

            chart1.Series(0).Label = "PSS"
            chart1.Series(1).Label = "USS"

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: One of the problems I am noticing is that T is trying to be converted from a string to an integer. I tried adding "TextBox11.Text = Form1.T" in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the code from the TextChanged event in to a public sub that takes the T variable as a parameter on the same form.  From your first form you can just call the public sub directly without having to worry about using a hidden text box and it's events.

Something along the lines of...

```
Public Class Form2
     Public sub TimerChange(T as integer)
         ...
     End Sub
End Class
```

Then in the main form

```
Dim frm as new Form2
frm.show
frm.TimerChange(T)
```